# Equivalence of two measures $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My question is somehow similar to these equations [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140805/proof-using-monotone-class-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1), [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008478/understanding-if-two-finite-measures-agree-on-a-pi-system-then-they-agree-on), and [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639494/equivalence-of-two-finite-measures-and-sigma-finite-measures)

> let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be the two measures on  $\mathbb R$ such that
> $\mu_1((a,b))= \mu_2((a,b))$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\mu_{1}(\{ a\})=0$, $\mu_{1}(\{ b\})=0$,
> $\mu_{2}(\{ a\})=0$, and $\mu_{2}(\{ b\})=0$. Show that $\mu_1$ and
> $\mu_2$ are equal.

I am not sure how would I use $\pi$-system and $\lambda$-system in here. Any hints are appreciated.

**Edit: In the question, it was not mentioned if the measures were finite, but it seems to be a necessary assumption. So, assume it is finite i.e $\mu_1((a,b))= \mu_2((a,b)) < \infty$**

Comment: Not true.  For example, $\mu_1$ the counting measure except it is $0$ at $0$, $\mu_2$ similar except it is $0$ at $1$.  There are no $a,b$ for which $\mu_i(\{a\})=0$ (or $\mu_i(\{b\})=0$) so the condition "$\mu_1((a,b))=\mu_2((a,b))$ for all $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ for which $\mu_1(\{a\})=\mu_2(\{a\})=\mu_1(\{b\})=\mu_2(\{b\})=0$" is vacuously true.  $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are measures on $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mu_1(\{0\})=0\neq1=\mu_2(\{0\})$, for example.

Comment: Have you omitted an assumption? If not, then I don't think this is true: take $\mu_1$ to be the counting measure and $\mu_2=2\mu_1$. Then the assumption is vacuously true, because $\mu_i(\{x\})$ is never $0$.

Comment: @user10354138 I have written it now as it is in my notes.

Comment: @user919322 You are missing an assumption here.  In the title you said finite measures, but in the question this assumption is never stated.  For finite measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ the conclusion holds (there are only countably many atoms which you can immediately deal with and the atomless case is easy to prove), but for $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$-valued measures this fails as both my and Rob's examples shows.

Comment: @user10354138 I have edited the question. Thank you!